# Is it OK to use 1/4" OSB over a standard subfloor before installing 3/4" hardwood on top?

Tags: flooring, subfloor, hardwood

I'm planning to install a hardwood floor to butt up against ceramic tile.  The tile looks like it will be 1/4" proud to the wood.  Can I install 1/4" OSB over the subfloor, then the paper, then the Oak Flooring?
Any problems long term?

Comment: Just keep in mind any areas this might cause issues in, such as steps designed for current height of the subfloor, or toilet flanges. Although 1/4" shouldn't be too big of a deal.

Comment: Are there instructions in the wood product you are using that discourages leveling compound?

Comment: No issues with toilet flanges as this is for living room and dining room adjacent to kitchen and hall way to bedrooms.- but thank you for reminding me of this.

Comment: The flooring will be installed by someone else.  So I do not know about restrictions concerning a leveling compound.  I've had no experience using leveling compound.  However, not sure it is pertinent here as the entire sub floor probably needs to be raised.  If it was just one area that was the question mark, I can see how leveling compound might be optimal.  (I'll know more when I get motivated to tear up the entire 700 sq ft of carpeting)

Comment: I wouldn't use leveling compound to bring an entire room up, nor is it well-suited under a nail-down hardwood floor in my experience. All those nails are going to beat it up pretty badly.

Answer (score 2):

That will work.  That's probably one of the better things to use to bring your floor level.

Answer (score 1):

You don't nail/staple 3/4" hardwood into OSB.   It won't stick.   In a couple years you will have a floating floor and issues.   OSB is great but it doesn't hold nails.

Comment: ok, thanks.  The OSB will be sandwiched between plywood subfloor and Oak hardwood.  The OSB is only 1/4".  Do you still think that could be an issue?

Comment: As long as the nails are long enough to reach into the plywood you should be fine.  You should also consider some glue/adhesive to eliminate potential squeak.

Comment: @Phaelaxz - I get it.  I don't believe in creating a weak point especially in the beginning of the nail.   You are giving it wiggle room.   No way I install the wrong subfloor for an expensive flooring.   OSB is for floating floors and carpet.

Comment: I agree any temp change and that OSB will be ripped apart as the oak expands or shrinks. +

Comment: OSB holds nails just fine (see also virtually any roof build in the last 30 years and most subfloors), but it's not the primary substrate anyway, being just 1/4" thick.

Comment: osb is fine for nails - why do you think it has problems with flooring nails?  we aren't talking about particle board.  @ed

Comment: @FreshCodemonger - OSB will microfracture due to bounce and humidity levels/movement over time.   The more humidity variance and the more people walk on the floors the less the OSB nails will hold.   Yea I get that it's only 1/4" and using it isn't the end of the world.   I just don't understand using something that has a greater chance at failure.

Comment: @dmoore Thanks for the explanation.  The manufacturer recommendations and the NWFA allow installation of nail down engineered hardwood flooring on top of 3/4" exterior stamped OSB (thickness is for deflection).  Do you disagree with them?

Comment: @FreshCodemonger - I get that.   I wonder what his hardwood manufacturer suggests - he didn't mention it being engineered.   With 80% of the engineered hardwood being some sort of MDF/crap backing I am not seeing how they can be super stringent on the subfloor.

Comment: @dmoore Preverco (pretty high end) flooring which uses baltic plywood core in their engineered product (pretty much the best grade of plywood) allows nail down install on OSB.  Just curious on your stance, would you never install it on OSB?

Comment: I would agree if the flooring is engineered the expansion and contraction due to temp and moisture variations will not be much different but true T&G is not saturated with resin and has much more movement, OSB or underpayment is fine for many flooring systems but I would be careful with real oak it is different.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger - I wouldn't.   Like I said before OSB is great.   The absolute preferred for floating hardwood/vinyl or carpet.   I don't nail things into OSB.   I have had this rule for 20 years.